# Changing label position in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, frame

We have a `UICollectionView` which has a prototype cell on the Storyboard. The cell has a `UILabel` ("`label`") in it, which is positioned without autolayout.

We set the frame of the label conditionally in the `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` with setFrame like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CategoryCell *cell;
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Category" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ...

    if (self.isViewTypeList) {            
        [((CategoryCell *)cell).label setFrame:FRAME_RECT];
    }

    ...

    return cell;
}
```

We have inspected it, and it seems that first of all it calls the label's `-setFrame:` with the Storyboard values when it gets to the dequeing, then our code follows, and this sets the new frames correctly. There is no other call other than these, but the label remains at it's original position on the screen.

What's wrong? Why is the new frame not set correctly? Is something other overrdiging it? Do I have to relayout or refresh it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following steps. This will work for you-

- In your storyboard or XIB file select prototype cell
- Select the label for which you want to change frame
- Set the `tag` property of it in `Attributes Inspector (View Section)`, like set `tag = 101`

After that in your code section do this -

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//...
    CategoryCell *cell;
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Category" 
                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //...
    if (self.isViewTypeList) {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        [lbl setFrame:FRAME_RECT];
    }
    //...
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck Autolayout from xib . It may help to change the frame.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //...
    //instead of
    //CategoryCell *cell;
    //cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Category" 
    //                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CategoryCell *cell = (CategoryCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Category"
                                                                                   forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //sure reuse-identifier is "Category"?

    //...
    if (self.isViewTypeList) {
        //instead of
        //[((CategoryCell *)cell).label setFrame:FRAME_RECT];
        [cell.label setFrame:FRAME_RECT];
    }
    //...
    return cell;
}
```

---

also go through this link and see if you are missing some crucial steps:
http://ashfurrow.com/blog/uicollectionview-example

Comment: Setting other properties of the cell (like background color) works fine, so this can't be the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Autolayout will override your calls to `setFrame:`.
You can add some outlets in your cell with the label's constraints, and change those to change the frame.

Comment: There is no autolayout and there aren't any constraints.