# Change frame of UIView in UICollectionViewCell in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, frame, uicollectionviewcell

My problem is very similar to this one, though the selected correct answer (which is just to use tags) didn't work for me (nor did any other answer): [Changing label position in UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686778/changing-label-position-in-uicollectionviewcell).

I have a UICollectionView with a custom UICollectionViewCell. The cell has a UIView in it, which is referenced via IBOutlet property. I'm simply trying to change the frame within the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, and while the frame of the UIView *is* in fact changed, it is subsequently ignored, or not honored.

However, once the UICollectionView is scrolled a bit and it begins reusing cells, the reused cells *do* honor the previous change to the UIView's frame, and the UIView looks just like it should. So for some reason the first time `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is called for a particular cell, the frame change is ignored, but is subsequently honored once the cell is reused.

Actually, something more curious which I just noticed is that a reused cell has the *size* of the frame that had been previously changed, but keeps the original *origin,* which happens to be (0, 0), though I'm trying to update it to something like (0, 50).

Changing other properties of the UIView works fine, such as changing the background color. What might be happening to prevent the UIView's frame from initially changing?

Comment: How are you changing the frame? Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, here and below. I'm changing the frame just using `setFrame`, and I am using auto layout. Below you mentioned that it is better to update constraints rather than frames directly when using auto layout? Do you think the frame changes made in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` are being overridden by subsequent auto layout actions (...but then for whatever reason honored on cell reuse)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you definitely should not set frames if you're using auto layout. You can try turning it off, and see if that fixes the problem, but I would stick with auto layout and change your code to adjust those constraints.

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar, I decided to just updated the constraints of the view, which worked perfectly (of course). Do you want to submit your advice again as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score -1):

UICollectionViewCell does not update frames for views that are defined in storyboard or xib files.

You have to create the view programmatically in your custom cells initWithFrame and/or awakeFromXib files.

Cheers!

hmmmm

I may be mistaken. I know this is true for UITableViewCell
[Cannot update UI object's frame in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872987/cannot-update-ui-objects-frame-in-uitableviewcell)

Comment: That's interesting. I have a UIImageView as a subview of the aforementioned UIView which *is* updating its frame perfectly, just as expected in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. So it's strange that some views' frames would be updated fine but others not, isn't it? Also, why then is it eventually working once a cell is reused?

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can update the views inside a collection view cell made in the storyboard, just like any other view.

Comment: @rdelmar please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872987/cannot-update-ui-objects-frame-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: ran into the same problem for UITableViewCell. Let us know if this fixes it @shibbowhat

Comment: Sure it works (but it's a work around), but you can change the frame of cell subviews. The problem is probably because of auto layout. If you're using auto layout, you should change the size or position of a view by modifying its constraints, not directly changing its frame.

Comment: I don't use autolayout.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use auto layout. If you don't, you can directly change the frame of a cell subview made in a storyboard with setFrame: just like any other view.

Comment: If you call it in cellForRowAtIndexPath it does update the view.